# C# method returns list by reference instead of by value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with a static list as shown below:

```
public class Context
{
    private static readonly List<Definition> definitions;
    
    static Context()
    {
        definitions = LoadXML("path-to-xml-file.xml"));
    }

    public static List<Definition> GetDefinitions()
    {
        return definitions;
    }
}
```

My problem is making calls to `GetDefinitions()` seems to return the list by reference instead of by value, because when I do this elsewhere in my code:

```
var defs = Context.GetDefinitions().ToList();
defs.ForEach(a =>
{
    a.Name = a.Alias ?? a.Name;
});
```

all subsequent calls to `Context.GetDefinitions()` will return the modified list - not the original one, hence my conclusion that `defs` is not a value but a reference to the `definitions` list.

I tried adding the `.ToList()` in an attempt to decouple the reference but still I get the same result.

I am also open to a workaround, which allows me to use `.Select()` instead of `.ForEach()` in my sample code.

Comment: `ToList()` will create a new object and return a reference to that new list. If you change it to `return definitions.ToList()` you will get a new list and not a reference to the original one.

Comment: @klekmek: But the new list will still contain the same references to the same objects as the original list. Changes to the `Name` property will still be visible via the original list.

Comment: I would suggest reading https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html thoroughly. Fundamentally, if you want to create an *entirely independent list* so that nothing you can do via the new list can affect anything in the old one, you need to deep-clone all the elements... or use value types throughout, or use immutable types. We don't know what `Definition` looks like, which makes it hard to give any more concrete advice.

Comment: Thank you for the literature Jon Skeet. 'Definitiion` has simple value types, so Makus' solution works perfectly with `MemberwiseClone`. I'll use the reading material as a starting point to understand the underlying concept

Comment: It does indeed sound like you want to make your `Definition` class immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the list does not store the items itself, but rather references to the items. Even if you create a new list (e.g. with `ToList()`), the referenced items stay the same.

In order to fix this, you need to clone the items in the list so that you have a  independent copy of the data. You can implement `ICloneable` on the items and use return the list like this:

```
public static List<Definition> GetDefinitions()
{
    return definitions.Select(x => (Definition)x.Clone()).ToList();
}
```

This way you create a new list that contains the cloned items. However, cloning an item is a tedious task if you need to clone a deeply nested class structure. For a flat structure, using [`MemberwiseClone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-6.0#system-object-memberwiseclone) is an easy way.

Comment: The big problem with the `ICloneable` interface is that it doesn't specify whether the cloning is deep or shallow, which makes it essentially useless for general code.